# Can $U+U\subset V$ imply $\overline{U}\subset V$ for any open sets $U$ and $V$ in a topological vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is a lemma about topological vector spaces:

> **Lemma** $\mathbf{2.1.1.}$ Let $X$ be a topological vector space.
>
> 1. Every neighborhood of zero is absorbing.
> 2. For every neighborhood $V$ of zero there exists a neighborhood $U$ of zero so that
>      (a) $U$ is balanced;
>      (b) $U+U\subset V$; and
>      (c) the closure $\overline U$ is contained in $V$.
>
> **Proof.** Fix a neighborhood $V$ of zero. For all $x\in X$ we have $0x=0\in V$, so that $tx\in V$ for $t$ small by the continuity of scalar multiplication. This proves $(1)$. The continuity of addition at $(0,0)\in X\times X$ implies the existence of a neighborhood $V_1$ of zero such that $V_1+V_1\subset V$, and the continuity of multiplication at $(0,0)\in C\times\Bbb F$ implies the existence of a neighborhood $V_2$ of zero, and of $\delta>0$, such that $\lambda V_2\subset V_1$ whenever $|\lambda|<\delta$. The set $\bigcup_{|\lambda|<\delta}\lambda V_2$ obviously satisfies conditions (a) and (b). To conclude the proof, it is enough to see that (c) actually follows from (b). Indeed, if $x\in\overline U$, then $(x-U)\cap U\ne\varnothing$; thus $x\in U+U\subset V$. $\;\square$

(Original image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PFAC.png).)

I don't follow the very last step:

> if $x\in \overline{U}$, then $x-U\cap U\not=\emptyset$.

If $x\in U$, then the statement is obvious since $0\in U$. What if $x\in U\setminus \overline{U}$? Do we always have

> $
> U+U\subset V
> $ implies $\overline{U}\subset V$ for any open set $U$ and $V$ in $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U$ is a nbhd of $0$, so $x=x-0\in x-U$, and $x-U$ is open, so $x-U$ is a nbhd of $x$. But $x\in\operatorname{cl}U$, so every nbhd of $x$ has non-empty intersection with $U$, and in particular $(x-U)\cap U\ne\varnothing$. Note that I used crucially the fact that $U$ is not just open, but specifically a nbhd of $0$.

Comment: Ah, since specifically $U$ is a nbhd of $0$, $x-U$ is a neighborhood of $x$?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, for the reason that I gave: on the one hand $x\in x-U$ (because $0\in U$), and on the other hand $x-U$ is open (because $U$ is open).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So the key property is that $0\in U$. Without this assumption, the implication $U+U\subset V\Rightarrow \overline{U}\subset V$ might be false, I think? I don't have a counterexample though.

Comment: @Jack: You’re welcome. Here’s a counterexample. For your vector space take $\Bbb R$. Let $U=(0,1)$ and $V=(0,2)$; then $U+U=V$, but $$0\in(\operatorname{cl}U)\setminus V=[0,1]\setminus(0,2)=\{0\}\;.$$